# How can I measure length of signal in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have model with "matlab function block" in which I have recursive least square method. Recursive algorithm needs to know length of incoming signal in order to work correctly. But when I use command N=length(y) it returns me length N= 1. But  I think it should give me higher length.
[Simulink model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mlVQ.png)

Matlab function block code "rls_iden6"

```
function [P,N] = fcn(u,y)
  %% 
  N = length(y);
  sigma=1;       
  C = sigma*eye(2);      %p
  P = ones(2,1);

  z= [y; u];
  lamda=1;
  for n=1:N
  sample_out = y(n);
  C = (C - ( (C*z*z'*C)/( lamda+(z'*C*z) ) ))/lamda;
  P = P + (C*z* (sample_out - (z'*P)));  
  end
```

My final code should look like it's shown below, because it works in matlab workspace. Simulink should give me 5 parameters instead of just 2.

```
load data_cela.mat
  u=U; %input
  y=Y; %output

  %%
  input = 3;
  output = 2;
  system = input + output;   
  N = length(y);              
  %initial conditions
  sigma = 1;        
  C = sigma*eye(system);      
  P = ones(system,1);        
  lamda = 1;               %forgetting factor

  for n=3:N
      for i=1:2
          W(i) = y(n-i);          %output
      end
      for i=1:3
          V(i) = u(n-i+1);        %input
      end
      z = [V';W'];
      sample_out = y(n);
      pom(n)= z' * P;
      error(n) = y(n) - pom(n); 
      C = (C - ( (C*z*z'*C)/( lamda+(z'*C*z) ) ))/lamda;

      P = P + (C*z* (sample_out - (z'*P) ) );
      change(1:system,n) = P;
  end
  f_param = [P(1:3);-P(4:5)];
  num = [P(1:3,1)];
  den = [1;-P(4:5,1)];
  num1 = num(3,1);
  trasferfunction = tf(num1,den',1)
```

Result:

```
0.002879
----------------------
z^2 - 1.883 z + 0.8873
```

Comment: The output of a transfer function block can only be a scalar, so your `y` signal can only possible have one value in it.  Presumably you need to buffer the output of the transfer function to create a vector values `y`.  One way of creating a buffer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194078/circular-buffer-in-simulink

Comment: Ok thank you for response, I will try that.

Comment: Ok I tried that but it didn't work. But I found another solutions. I just put block "tapped delay" in front of matlab function and it shows me correct length of N. But now it shows me this error: Undefined function or variable 'W' and 'V'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class. And when I set initial condition before loop V=0;W=0; It will stay 0 during the simulation and gives me another error that size of matrix don't agree.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a buffer before signal to convert the scalar to matrix. Then after the buffer has been added set the buffer size to the amount of data you want, i.e. by setting it to 2 will make 2 rows and 1 column. This will help you to get the data however, for setting delay properly you will require to set buffer overlap to 1.

Hope this helps.