# Simulink MATLAB function block with vector inputs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm new to Simulink and am working on a project.

The bigger picture is that I want to gather different sensor data, pick out an interval of that, and in my Matlab functions analyze it, a kind of adaption. It feels like I have a fundamental misconception since I thought my Matlab scripts could work directly in Simulink.  I have a couple of Matlab function blocks which in Matlab takes vectors as inputs, but when I use a source such as "from workspace" I get the error that it cannot handle more than one value at the same time: Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1.

So I wonder if there is any neat way of collecting a given interval of a continuous flow of sensor data (as a beginning, the raw input will just be a vector which will represent sensor data) so that it could be analyzed by some Matlab functions?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the way you are using the `From Workspace` block, not the `MATLAB Function` block.  (That is, bringing scalar data into the model rather than vector data, and when fed into the MATLAB Function block and you try to index element 2, element 2 doesn't exist.)  If you turn signal dimension on  Display > Signals and Ports > Signal Dimensions what does it tell you?

Comment: @PhilGoddard If you mean the number next to the source symbol it says 1. Is that the total size of the source? I thougt that was symbolizing that simulink takes one data point at each time step.

Comment: @PhilGoddard I want to create a kind of buffer, which takes in an array from workspace and saves up an interval of a given size which is to be sent to one of my Matlab function blocks. I've now tried a "for each"-subsystem which uses vector concatenators. but it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions? I attach a print screen of the inside of my "for each"-subsystem: https://imgur.com/a/bRqmtzu As you see, the node at hand is a part of a demux-mux of all inputs and outputs.

Comment: There are a couple of examples of creating buffers in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194078/circular-buffer-in-simulink